# Supabase row level security policy not returning any data

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

I have 2 tables: `users` and `organisations`. Users have an `organisation_id` connecting them to an `organisation`. I want to allow `users` to read the other `users` that belong to the same `organisation` as they do. I think it should be something like the following:

```sql
(auth.uid()=id) 
or
(
    type='admin' and
    exists (
        select 1
        from users as _users
        where users.organisation_id=_users.organisation_id
    )
)
```

So:

- A user is able to read their own user record
- A user is able to read records for other `users` that share their `organisation_id`

The above query, however, is not returning any records at all. It doesn't even return the user who is logged in.

Another way I've tried is like so:

```sql
(auth.uid()=id) 
or
(
    type='admin' and
    users.organisation_id in (
        select organisation_id
        from users as _users
        where users.organisation_id=_users.organisation_id
    )
)
```

But this has the same result unfortunately. If someone could point out where I'm going wrong I'd really appreciate it - the example [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/postgres/row-level-security#minimize-joins) seems to be close, but I need to use the same table as the policy is applied to to check the records

Comment: You haven't stated which table you have this policy on or what columns are available in this table. Also have you tried with only the `auth.uid() = id` to see if it work?

Comment: I am applying the policy to the `users` table, to allow a user to read other users that belong to the same organisation. `auth.uid() = id` on its own does work, but using it with the `or` statement (2nd code block) doesn't work.

Relevant columns in the tables are that the `users` table has an `organisation_id` table which relates to the `id` column of the `organisations` table.

Comment: You have a `type='admin'` in there too. does the user you are logged in as have 'admin' in the `type` column?